# Jquery Ajax POST method

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova

I am trying to do a POST method like this

```
  var url = 'http://myurl';

  var data1 = {
                key1:"value",
                key2:"value",
                key3:"value",
            };
            $.support.cors = true;
            e.preventDefault();
            var jObject = JSON.stringify(data1);
            $.ajax({
                beforeSend: function(xhrObj) {
                    xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                },
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: {JObject: jObject},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {


                    alert("Succes" + data);


                },
                error: function(xhr, type) {
console.log('Internal Error Occoured!' + xhr.responseText);

                }
            });
        });
```

I got error which contains a title like this .
    IIS 7.5 Detailed Error - 500.50 - URL Rewrite Module Error.

Is there any error in my code.This post call works with url parameters in POST man. Please help me .I am stuck with this for last one week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"IIS 7.5 Detailed Error - 500.50 - URL Rewrite Module Error"

the error is a server side error

IIS7.5 is a server application provided by microsoft

and the URL Rewrite Module is a module that helps you rewrite urls

like :

example.com/index.php?action=user_details&username=blabla

->

example.com/user/blabla

to my knowledge it is a server side problem, not your's

but to be sure do this :

put your url in browser and press go and when the page loads completely, copy the url you see now in the browser (if it is changed) and use that for your URL.

besides : while doing the line above, if you saw any server errors, be sure it's not your problem and contact the admin to fix it :)

( + and sorry for the bad english :D )

Comment: This is in JQuery mobile.Is that the problem

Comment: nope, I'm using the same method (but using xml for api's output) and even using mod_rewrite too.

Comment: did you followed all redirects (is there is any) and using the last one ?